# What license should I be using when selling to reproduction companies?

Tags: pricing, selling

I was thinking about selling some of my photos to companies that may reproduce and re-sell the images i.e. postcards, posters, stock framed pictures.

The problem is I am a little unsure as to what sort of pricing and payment structure I should apply to the sale of each photo. For example should I be selling them as a one off premium price or should I be pricing based on reproduction rates? I also thought about the possibility of a revenue share based on sales.

Has anyone had experience with this sort of selling process and if so could you offer some advice on the correct type of path to take?

Comment: Have you actually talked to such companies? My impression is that there's such a glut of cheap photography these days (for better and for worse!) that they'll set the terms, not you.

Comment: See: [How can I make extra money with photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/how-can-i-make-extra-money-with-photography)

Comment: I don't know what the industry is like these days, but it used to be the case that if your name wasn't part of the product, you weren't getting royalties out of the deal. You sell publication rights in the smallest niche (format(s), region and time frame) that you can get away with or charge extra for the lost markets, and walk away with a one-time, *possibly* renewable payment. Because it's old info, I can't really make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For limited sales I'm using [Hahnemuehle's authenticity certificate system](http://www.hahnemuehle.com/site/en/219/certificate-of-authenticity.html). Pricing is about $3.40 per certificate.

Regarding the postcards, you are selling the usage of the photo for a period of time, for a total quantity (or unlimited).  My advice to you is you should not base your pricing on volume because you can never be sure about any company's marketing strategy. My advice to you is sticking with one or two year time period. If they are satisfied with the photo, you can demand a bit more when they renew.

With stock photos, whether you like it or not, you will sell them for forever so factor that into your pricing, because you can never control digital copies.