# How do I get from starting off photography to selling my photos?

Tags: wildlife, selling, amateur

I'm a starting wildlife photographer!

My question is, how would I get to from just taking pictures to actually selling them and everything? I'm kinda new to most of this, It would be great to get some advice!

Comment: Build a time machine and go back in time to before the digital/internet age to when people were actually willing to pay more than a few cents for the rights to a photo.

Comment: Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11417/9161

Comment: Selling to whom? I got a couple acquaintances who were happy to buy prints of my pics to hang in their living room; at least it's more unique than something from Ikea.

Answer (score 0):

There are several photography sites that will put your photos up for sale and take percentage if they sell. Realize the thousands, if not millions are photos are up for sale. Wildlife is tough to sell because it doesn’t fit into the realm of what most corporate buyers are looking for. Check out EyeEm, Adobe and ViewBug, all of which have this for their users. ViewBug also will provide you the tools for starting your website.

Answer (score 0):

As a easy start I would recommend getting involved with a Stock Photo site. The better ones are a bit tricky to get accepted at and they will give you an eye for whats sells and what does not (you will be surprised).

You could also print and frame your own work and ask restaurants, offices etc. to hang it in their space with a note and your contact details.

Participate in contests and photography workshops etc.. if not to improve then at least to network and get involved with others.

Photography as a hobby is great. Selling photos is a whole different world.