# How can amateurs monetize photos?

Tags: stock-photography, selling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way for a hobbyist to start generating income from photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9114/what-is-the-best-way-for-a-hobbyist-to-start-generating-income-from-photos)
>   [How can I make extra money with photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/how-can-i-make-extra-money-with-photography)

I am an amateur who sometimes takes pictures of nature or random things. I've been told by several people that my pictures are worth money.

How can I monetize my best shots?

I don't really want to do a lot of work, editing, SEO or whatever. I'm looking for an easy way where I would just upload my pictures somewhere and let it go.

Maybe stock photos? People buying prints? I have no idea how that works...

EDIT: maybe a link to see which type of photography I do can help http://www.flickr.com/photos/nasht00/

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/how-can-i-make-extra-money-with-photography