# How much is appropriate to charge once I gain enough experience?

Tags: photography-basics, pricing, amateur

So, I'm trying to start my own photography business but I am very much an amateur. I love taking photos of nature so that will definitely be something I'll keep doing. I will be starting to practice portrait & possibly pet & newborn photography as well. I am in the process of getting more gear as well. I'm not planning on charging for a long time, as I am no where near good enough for that. I was just wondering though, I'm hoping to make at least roughly $1000 a month when I do start to charge. Is this okay? I have no idea how to properly price (I have been researching for days but I'm overwhelmed). I know I probably sound dumb, I'm nowhere near being an expert & I don't want to step on anyone's toes, I just want to contribute financially for my family.
Thank you.

Comment: If you are charging for work, then by definition you are a professional and not an amateur.

Comment: Well yes, but for now I'm most definitely an amateur & I am not comfortable charging for my work just yet. I want more experience under my belt first. I just can't seem to figure out pricing tho :/ it would be nice to be able to plan a bit so that's why I'm asking now :)

Comment: Hi, J.S1314, and welcome to Photography SE! We're a community that has a vast archive of questions that have already been answered. The way it works here is rather than ask the same questions over and over, we're supposed to guide you to questions that have already been created here. There are a few other, existing questions about how much someone starting out should charge for photographic services. What have you found in them? What have you not found in them that doesn't answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much should an amateur charge for a portrait session?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/how-much-should-an-amateur-charge-for-a-portrait-session)

Comment: Related: [What is the best way for a hobbyist to start generating income from photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9114/15871)

Comment: What you charge also depends on local prevailing rates. What are other photographers in your locality charging?

Comment: You say that you are a long way from being good enough to become a professional. People who pay for your work expect a professional. If you cannot do this you will make a name of a bad photographer which will be blocking you when, one day, you become a real professional. Getting a good name takes a long time, getting a bad name is done in a second.

Comment: To Marco, that's exactly why I'm not charging now. As stated in my original post/question, I am no were near ready to start charging people for my work. I'm still practicing. I've only been doing basic "photography" from my phone which is sub par, but I'm working towards actually making a career out of this. I love photography & I want to do right by it. All I want is to make a name (& a good 1) for myself & help support my family while doing something I love. I guess I worded my overall question badly, because I wouldn't be charging until I actually know what I'm doing.